# Scales of plots in pymc

Tags: python, matplotlib, bayesian, pymc3, pymc

I would like to have probability instead of frequency in the vertical axis of my traceplot in PyMC. How is it possible to set?
The examples are in the photos. I realize it is easy to transform by dividing it by the number of samples, but is it possible to visualize it?

[image: Example_1]

[image: Example_2]

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: Even though the axis says "Frequency" they look like correctly scaled density functions to my eye (e.g., about mean height 10 with width of 0.1, and mean height 0.05 with width of 20).  Also, have you looked [the documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/api/plots.html#pymc3.plots.traceplot)? For trace plots there is a `transform` argument.